# Difference between socket.emit() vs socket.on() in ngx-socket-io

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new to ngx-socket-io and I want to know the difference between socket.emit vs socket.on in ngx-socket-io.

which is better to use and why?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can check https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about this module ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io)) then, `.emit` and `.on` are to different things. In the documentation they clearly says:

**`socket.on()`**:

> Takes an event name and callback. Works the same as in Socket.IO.

**`socket.emit()`**:

> Sends a message to the server. Optionally takes a callback. Works the same as in Socket.IO.

Summary, `.emit('test')` triggers an event named ***test*** and `.on('test')` listen to an event named ***test***.